# If $F_n<a<F_{n+1}<b<F_{n+2}$ for $n\ge4$,establish that the sum $a+b$ cannot be a Fibonacci number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

> **If $F_n<a<F_{n+1}<b<F_{n+2}$ for $n\ge4$,establish that the sum $a+b$ cannot be  a Fibonacci number.**

I'm thinking of showing that $a+b$ cannot be written as the sum of two preceeding terms.**But don't know HOW?**

Please tell me how can i attain the desired result...

Comment: try to compare $a+b$ with $F_{n+3,2,1}$

Comment: Why the condition $n\ge4$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:It is mentioned in the source .But, i think it is useless to mention this restriction as it holding for $n=1,2,3,4$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. We show that $a+b$ is strictly in between two consecutive Fibonacci numbers:
$$F_{n+2}=F_{n}+F_{n+1}<a+b<F_{n+1}+F_{n+2}=F_{n+3}.$$

Comment: Nice!!................